# Android layout doesn't load in visual studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using `Xamarin 4.0.1.145, Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 and Android SDK (24.3.3)`.

I want design  and drag tools from tools box on `main.axml` but designer is disabled and I don't know why designer of Android  or `main.axml` doesn't load?

Comment: Can you add a relevant screen shot and a screenshot of your Android Sdk versions? Can you ensure you update your Android Sdk fully as well?

Comment: my be this problem for incomplete update,now i update sdk ,unfortunately  speed of internet is very slow,after complete update,if the problem don't solve,then  i send screen shot of sdk

Comment: Unfortunately after update sdk and Xamarin the problem is not solved. now i send detail of my system and scren shot of sdk 
please help
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
Installed Version: Enterprise
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU 00322-90150-00888-AA451 Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU
Xamarin 4.1.0.530 (2e39740) Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
Xamarin.Android 6.1.0.71 (4e27558) Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Comment: sorry i forget send screen shot of sdk


[ver sdk][1]
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bkh0y.png

[tools][2]
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FpyAv.png

Answer (score 0):

my problem was solved.i uninstall xamarin and jdk completly then install xamarin 4.0.1.145 and jdk 7.
may be problem from elsewhere but the problem was solved by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. And it got resolved after updating the Android SDK.

**Tools --> Android --> Android SDK Manager**